# org.springframework.dao.CannotAcquireLockException: could not execute statement

Tags: database, hibernate-5

org.springframework.dao.CannotAcquireLockException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not execute statement

Full stack trace of the error

org.springframework.dao.CannotAcquireLockException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not execute statement
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:238)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:388)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:347)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.flush(HibernateTemplate.java:809)

Any help how to resolve this issue?